# Ruby 正規表現 空白のみを検知するには？

Tags: ruby

Rubyで空白のみの文字列だった場合、それを検知する方法がわかりません。
調べてみても、空白を取り除く方法ばかりで、空白のみの場合はどうすれば良いでしょうか？

半角・全角に対応したいです。

Comment: POSIX文字クラスを使って `str.match(/^[[:space:]]+$/)` とするのはどうでしょう。ドキュメントには「これらの POSIX 文字クラスは `\s` といった省略記法と異なり、 ASCIIコード範囲外の空白などを考慮に入れます。」と記載されていて、いわゆる全角スペース文字(`U+3000`)にもマッチします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

空白がいわゆる半角スペースと全角スペースの2種類であれば

```
/\A[\x20\u3000]+\z/.match(str) 
#または str.match(/\A[\x20\u3000]+\z/)
#または str =~ /\A[\x20\u3000]+\z/
```

これで判定できます。`\x20`は半角空白、`\u3000`は全角空白です。スペース1文字ならともかく、今回の場合は[ 　]と書かないようにしましょう。

\Aは文字列の先頭、\zは文字列の末尾にマッチします。似たものに`^` `$`がありますがこれは行頭行末にマッチします。「文字列全体」を検査したいときは`\A` `\z`を使いましょう。`^` `$`を使うとバグのもとです。

```
/^[\x20\u3000]+$/.match("abc\n \ndef") # => #<MatchData " ">
```

タブなど他の空白扱いされる文字にもマッチさせたい場合はPOSIX文字クラスの:blank:を使って

```
/\A[[:blank:]]+\z/.match(str)
```

こんな風にかけます。

```
/\A[\s\u3000]+\z/.match(str) #半角の空白類文字+全角空白
/\A[[:space:]]+\z/.match(str) #Unicode的空白文字全般
```

こいつらは改行文字にもマッチします。

文字の意味についてはマニュアル読んでください。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fregexp.html

Comment: 大変わかりやすく、理解できました。ご回答ありがとうございました。